# How to use Image assets in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcasset

I would like to use the launch images from the xcasset; I've already tried some ways but I can't get it works.

I've the standard LaunchImage asset, and the image file are called `Default[@2x,...]`. Using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"];` always return nil. I've also tried with `@"Default"`, but no results.

Comment: Your answer didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Just want to use the compiled images separately in your application:

By-default LaunchImage asset would generate following files:

```
LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png
LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png
```

To find them use below:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Portrait"];
```

---

**Note:** 
3 steps required to setup the assets properly are mentioned below. Are you missing anything ?

My Images:[image]

Updating images in Launch Image source:
[image]

Drag and drop images in LaunchImage asset:
[image]